# ObjectDataSource 'odsMonthlyStatusReport' could not find a non-generic method 'GetMonthlyReportData' that has parameters: month, year

Tags: c#, asp.net, radgrid, objectdatasource

I am using RadGrid in Web Page and binding it using ObjectDataSource as below:

```
   <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsMonthlyStatusReport" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetMonthlyReport_Test" TypeName="atQuest.Projects.Sunway.IPRRequest">
                        <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlMonth" Name="month" PropertyName="SelectedValue"
                                Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true"  />
                            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlYear" Name="year" PropertyName="SelectedValue"
                                Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true"  />
                        </SelectParameters>
                    </asp:ObjectDataSource>

                    <telerik:RadGrid ID="GridReport" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AllowFilteringByColumn="True" ShowGroupPanel="True"
                    CellSpacing="0" GridLines="None" Width="100%" Skin="Outlook" DataSourceID="odsMonthlyStatusReport" OnItemDataBound="GridReport_ItemDataBound">

                            <ClientSettings AllowDragToGroup="True" />
                            <GroupingSettings CaseSensitive="false"></GroupingSettings>
                            <MasterTableView AllowFilteringByColumn="true" AllowMultiColumnSorting="false" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                                    CommandItemDisplay="Top" DataKeyNames="RequestID" EnableGroupsExpandAll="true"
                                    GroupLoadMode="Client" PageSize="50">

                            <CommandItemSettings ShowAddNewRecordButton="false" ShowExportToExcelButton="true" />
                            <SortExpressions>
                                <telerik:GridSortExpression FieldName="RequisitionNo" SortOrder="Descending" />
                            </SortExpressions>
                            <PagerStyle AlwaysVisible="True" PageSizeControlType="RadComboBox" Position="Bottom" PageSizes="50,100,150,200" />

                                        <Columns>
                                            //all GridBound columnc
                                        </Columns>
                                    </MasterTableView>
                                    <ExportSettings SuppressColumnDataFormatStrings="True" IgnorePaging="True" ExportOnlyData="True" Excel-Format="ExcelML" OpenInNewWindow="True" FileName="eAPDocHistory" Excel-FileExtension="xls">
                                    </ExportSettings>
                                </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Below is the Class file (IPRRequest.cs) code:

```
[DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select, true)]
        public static DataTable GetMonthlyReport_Test(string Month, string Year, string orderBy)
        {
            Data data = new Data();
            Dictionary<string, object> input = new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                {"@Month", Month},
                {"@Year", Year},
            };
            return data.ExecuteQuery(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "[Invoice].[usp_tbl_Request_Select_MonthlyStatusReport]", input);
        }
```

Then, I **Build** using "Debug" and "Release" option, and deploy the .dll
of "Release" folder to the server. It always throw below error:
[image]

As I can see all the code is correct in my case. Then why I am getting this error? Please let me know what is wrong in my code or if anything missing. Please reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was due to missing 3rd parameter `string orderBy` (defined in .cs file) but not in `ObjectDataSource`. Added this line as below:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsMonthlyStatusReport" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetReportData" TypeName="atQuest.Projects.Sunway.IPRRequest">
     <SelectParameters>
          <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlMonth" Name="month" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true"  />
          <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlYear" Name="year" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true"  />
          <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="" Name="orderBy" Type="String" />
     </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Error resolved.